# Adding jquery based on a clone children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, clone

I'm trying to make a function that takes a clone and add images in a loop, but it adds only one, the following codes:

My HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple />
   <ul id="img_public">
       <li>
         <img class="img_src" src="#" title="" alt="" />
         <p class="img_name"></p>
         <p class="img_size"></p>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

My JS:

```
if($("#files").length > 0) {
            var _URL  = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var clone = $('#img_public').children('li').clone();
            $('#img_public').html('');
            $("#files").change(function () {
                var file, img;
                $.each(this.files, function(i, elem) {
                    img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function(e) {
                        $('#img_public').append(clone);
clone.children('.img_src').attr('src',img.src).attr('alt',elem.name).attr('title',elem.name);
                        clone.children('.img_name').html(elem.name);
                        clone.children('.img_size').html(elem.size);
                    };

                    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(elem);
                });

            });
```